# Socket io vs Nodejs: died when 2k concurrent user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

My project have one module. It need to be real-time push data from json file from Server to Client. I am using Socket IO and Nodejs for listenning client. My idea is **server nodejs setInterval every 5 second** and check **current time**, and if valid then read json file and emit to all client. I try with **2k client** and socket io and nodejs died. I read data from folder with name **ttkqxs**, file name format is **1.json, 2.json**. Read and push very good but with 2k client and more i have trouble. Here is my code, what problem with it ???

```
// Dependencies
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
// Time config
var MN_START_HOUR = 16,
    MN_START_MIN = 5,
    MN_END_MIN = 45,
    MT_START_HOUR = 17,
    MT_START_MIN = 5,
    MT_END_MIN = 45,
    MB_START_HOUR = 18,
    MB_START_MIN = 5,
    MB_END_MIN = 45;
var intervalTime = 5000;
var MB_ID = 22;
var MB = 1;
var MT = 2;
var MN = 3;
var firstTimeMb = true;
var firstTimeMt = true;
var firstTimeMn = true;

// Server ready
http.listen(3113, function () {
console.log('Server listening on port: 3113 ');
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var min = date.getMinutes();
        var sec = date.getSeconds();
        var hour = date.getHours();
        console.log("CurrentTime: " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
        // Mien Bac
        if (hour === MB_START_HOUR && min >= MB_START_MIN && min <= MB_END_MIN) {
            if (firstTimeMb) {
                firstTimeMb = false;
                emitRegionData(MB, 'first_time_' + MB);
            }
            emitRegionData(MB, 'return_g_result_' + MB);
            emitProvincesData(MB);
        }
        // Miền Trung
        if (hour === MT_START_HOUR && min >= MT_START_MIN && min <= MT_END_MIN) {
            if (firstTimeMt) {
                firstTimeMt = false;
                emitRegionData(MT, 'first_time_' + MT);
            }
            emitRegionData(MT, 'return_g_result_' + MT);
            emitProvincesData(MT);
        }
        //Miền Nam
        if (hour === MN_START_HOUR && min >= MN_START_MIN && min <= MN_END_MIN) {
            if (firstTimeMn) {
                firstTimeMn = false;
                emitRegionData(MN, 'first_time_' + MN);
            }
            emitRegionData(MN, 'return_g_result_' + MN);
            emitProvincesData(MN);
        }

        // reset first time
        if (hour == 23) {
            firstTimeMb = true;
            firstTimeMt = true;
            firstTimeMn = true;
        }
    }, intervalTime);
});
/**
 * Get province data from json file and emit to all client
 * Desktop: Use in home page, province page
 * Mobile: Only use in province page
 * @param {int} pid Province id
 * @returns
 */
function emitProvinceData(pid) {
    var fileName = __dirname + '/ttkqxs/' + pid + '.json';
    fs.exists(fileName, function () {
        fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            io.sockets.emit('return_p_result_' + pid, content);
        });
    });
}
/**
 * Get province data from json file and emit to all client
 * Desktop: Use in home page, province page
 * Mobile: Only use in province page
 * @param {int} pid Province id
 * @returns
 */
function emitProvincesData(rid) {
    var fileName = __dirname + '/ttkqxs/mien' + rid + '.json';
    fs.exists(fileName, function () {
        fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            var ids = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(content)));
            for (var i in ids) {
                emitProvinceData(ids[i].id);
            }
        });
    });
}
/**
 * Emit Region data
 * Use in mobile for multiple province
 * @param {int} rid Region id
 * @returns
 */
function emitRegionData(rid, eventName) {
    var fileName = __dirname + '/ttkqxs/mien' + rid + '.json';
    fs.exists(fileName, function () {
        fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            var ids = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(content)));
            var files = [];
            for (var i in ids) {
                var pFileName = __dirname + '/ttkqxs/' + ids[i].id + '.json';
                files.push(pFileName);
            }
            async.map(files, readAsync, function (err, results) {
                io.sockets.emit(eventName, JSON.stringify(results));
            });
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Read file Async
 * @param {string} file File Path
 * @param {function} callback
 * @returns
 */
function readAsync(file, callback) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', callback);
}
```

Comment: Uhm... can you provide us with the stack trace of the error?

Comment: I see nodejs server doesn't working anymore, the timer not run, and no error or log message display in command line.

Comment: so it becomes unresponsive. First thing i would have done was move away from setInterval to setTimeout, to avoid a possible situation where the previous read/broadcast isn't done before the next starts.

Comment: But my business require emit to all client when content file is change, so my solution is read file every 5 seconds, as your opinion, I think is unresponsive :(

Comment: what causes the file to change? Best case scenario would be only emit when it changes, rather than every 5 seconds. Why emit the same data over and over and over and over?

Comment: How can i know file is change or not ? File content is updated by another task.

Comment: Have that other task emit to the server, which causes the server to emit to the clients.

Comment: also, side-note about my suggestion for setTimeout, setTimeout will still emit every n seconds if you set it up to. you simply set a setTimeout at the end when the task is complete, which starts it up again after n seconds.

Comment: But I think setTimeout will execute 1 times ? The setInterval function is seting to run every intervalTime

Comment: correct, it executes one time. here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/1d5273xw/ that shows how you can use the fact that it executes one time to have it run the function indefinitely, after an interval.

Comment: What difference between 2 solution ??? I think nodejs can handle more client than 2k.

Comment: simplify your test to rule out possible causes. As it currently stands, every 5 seconds, you're emitting several messages to every client, resulting in 2000*whatever messages sent every 5 seconds. Is the broadcast what is crashing it, or is it the fact that you have 2000 connections. My expectation is that it's hanging up on sending so many messages.

Comment: little bit of napkin math: if you're sending 10 messages (looks like you might be sending far more than that..) to each client every 5 seconds, you're sending 20k messages every 5 seconds, or, 4000 messages per second. that's a lot of data. does your server/network have enough resources to handle that much data?

Comment: I think you need to start thinking about spreading the load. 2k concurrent users on one server is a pretty hefty workload even for node. What if it becomes 5k, or 10k. Better to solve the underlying issue and distribute the load. As others have said the most likely problem here is that you're just saturating the network connection. If you monitor the network bandwidth does it cap out?

Comment: What happend if i switch to ajax request. Before user nodejs and socket io. I use ajax request and it work fine. So nodejs is too weak ???